# Pass another argument with initWithFrame:CGRectMake()

Tags: ios, objective-c, button

Hey I have a class `RqButton` deriving from `UIButton` that I use to personalise my buttons.

If If do `button = [[RqButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xz, yz, sq, sq)];` everything is working as expected but I want to pass another parameter to `RqButton` and I don't know how.

This is my `RqButton.m`

```
#import "RqButton.h"

@implementation RqButton


+ (RqButton *)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)type
{return [super buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect r:(int)r
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    float width =  CGRectGetWidth(rect);
    float height =  CGRectGetHeight(rect);

    UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.99f green:0.95f blue:0.99f alpha:1.00f];


    CGFloat BGLocations[2] = { 0.0, 1.0 };
    CGFloat BgComponents[8] = { 0.99, 0.99, 0.0 , 1.0,
        0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 1.0 };
    CGColorSpaceRef BgRGBColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef bgRadialGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(BgRGBColorspace, BgComponents, BGLocations, 2);

    UIBezierPath *roundedRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height) cornerRadius: 5];
    [roundedRectanglePath addClip];

    CGPoint startBg = CGPointMake (width*0.5, height*0.5);
    CGFloat endRadius= r;

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(ctx, bgRadialGradient, startBg, 0, startBg, endRadius, kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(BgRGBColorspace);
    CGGradientRelease(bgRadialGradient);

    [borderColor setStroke];
    roundedRectanglePath.lineWidth = 2;
    [roundedRectanglePath stroke];
}

@end
```

You see that I want to be able to call the class while passing the `CGrect` and the int r in order to use it in the line **CGFloat endRadius= r;**

Of course, `button = [[RqButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xz, yz, sq, sq) :1];` wouldn't work like this, but now, what's the way of actually doing it?

Thanks for your help, Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is create a new `init` method within RqButton that will use the `initWithFrame`'s `super`. Add another parameter to your custom init to use within the custom initialization.

**RqButton.m**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)rect radius:(CGFloat)r
{
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:rect])
    {
        // apply your radius value 'r' to your custom button as needed.
    }
    return self;
}
```

Make sure to add this method to your header file as well so that you can access it publicly. You can now call this method from wherever you want to `init` your RqButton like so:

```
RqButton *customButton = [[RqButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xz, yz, sq, sq) radius:2.0];
```